# How do I configure a route in ASP.NET Web Forms to receive a Json Post from a third party API (Webhook)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to configure a route such as `https://example.com./api/NotesApi/WebHook/pix`, to receive a HTTP `POST` request from a third party API. My site is ASP.NET Webforms running on .NET 4.6.1. `Global.asax` looks like this, under `app_start`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", New With {Key .id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.[Optional])
```

And then in the `NotesApiController.vb` I have

```
Public Sub WebHook(ByVal request As HttpRequestMessage)
    Dim json = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    ...
End Sub
```

I tested that I can trigger this method by sending a post to

```
https://example.com./api/NotesApi/WebHook
```

but the API sends the request to

```
https://example.com./api/NotesApi/WebHook/pix
```

and I have no idea how to configure this `/pix` part in the controller. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it working by applying the good ole Trial 'n Error method:

```
         <HttpPost()>
    Public Function WebHook(pix As JObject) As HttpStatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", 
                               "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/pix", 
                               New With {Key .id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.[Optional])
```

Comment: Jee, as easy as that! Thanks a lot. But what about my other methods that don't need this "/pix" thing appended?